# Using the same power supply produces no sound

Tags: amplifier, audio, speakers, line, level

**AS SOME OF YOU ASKED, here is the video showing the connection and the problem: https://photos.app.goo.gl/GRsxQ783Rec6jVxo6**

One clue that I got today: the problem happens EVEN if I disconnect the external spekaer from the mini amplifier! So the speaker wires dont make any difference in this problem!

I have a very old digital piano which does not have LINE OUT but it has a built-in speaker. I want to connect this digital piano to external speakers so I can get louder sound.

The first thing I did was to build a pretty simple voltage attenuator using 2 resistors so I can tap the 2 wires going to the built-in speaker of the piano and produce a 1 V line out. It works fine and I can succesfully generate the LINE OUT.

Then I connected this LINE OUT to a mini amplifier (PAM8610) and connected this amplifier to an external speaker. Here is where the problem comes: when I use the same power supplier to power the piano and amplifier, the sound does not come out in the external speaker and the built-in speaker of the piano stops immediatly producing any sound. If I use 2 separate power supplies, one for the piano and one for the mini amplifier, it works fine, the sound is great and it works on both speakers (the built-in speaker of the piano and the external piano at the same time.)

The power supply is not the problem, it can easily handle 10A / 12V. The piano itself uses only 1.5A and the mini amp + external speaker uses no more than 1A. So the problem is not in overloading in the power supply.

I did the diagram below so you can see it better. What is going on? Why does using the same power supply cause this problem? Might I damage my digital piano doing this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the Piano and Amplifier each getting both the +12V and Ground connections from your power supply?

Comment: Please post a photo of the piano amplifier and connections to the speaker.

Comment: Please draw a 'real' schematic (preferably using the built-in schematic editor you'll find when you [edit] your question) and show us where exactly you're connecting *all* of the wiring between these various pieces of equipment.

Comment: @td127 Yes, I have a power supply connected to my outlet (220V AC) and it generates 12V DC. When I connect this power supply to both piano and mini amplifier, no sound happens. Any idea might be happening?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I am on my parents house now, when I get home I will take a picture!

Comment: `connect this power supply to both piano and mini amplifier` ... what did you connect to what? (where does each wire go?)

Comment: Traditionally, power supplies with [this](https://media.cablematic.com/__sized__/images_1000/ab03200-01-thumbnail-1080x1080-70.jpg) type of output jacks have the inner pin connected to positive. But especially some audio equipment accepting that type of jacks (e.g. pedals, audio interfaces) have this connection reversed i.e. the inner pin is connected to GND. If at least one of your audio equipment is that type of "special" equipment then it might be shorting the supply so none of your equipment supplied from that power supply can work. Or even you may have damaged your equipment.

Comment: @jsotola I made a video so you can see! Could you please check the question again?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I made a video as you requested, could you please take a look? I edited the top of the question so you can see it!

Answer (score 1):

They make devices to do just this, they are called DI (Direct Injection) boxes. They can be acquired isolated and with ground lift if you want it. They are not very expensive. You may also get them with an isolation transformers.

In the DIY mode:
Try adding capacitors in your audio out from the speaker, one in each line.

If that does not work use an isolation transformer. These are readily available and not to expensive.

Good Luck and enjoy the music.

Comment: Thank you my friend, but I cant by those DI for now :( I am stuck with what I got... regarding the capacitor you told, I think it would not make any difference (respectfully) because if I disconnect the speakers from the mini amplifier the same problem hapens! I made a video of that, could you please check my edit to see the video?

Answer (score 1):

Please double check your DC power supply connections.

[image]

The digital piano may not be getting powered on account of a wiring error with a shared supply.

A multimeter check, for supply voltage on the digital piano barrel connector, would ascertain that.

Comment: I did exactly what you said, and my connections are exactly as you said :) One new piece of clue, is that the problem happens even if I disconnect the external speaker from the amplifier! I made a video showing what I got, would you mind take a look? I edited my question and added the link!

Comment: You show the piano speaker output going through an isolating transformer, but we don't know that this is true. Most modern amplifier circuits do not have transformer outputs. Many, like the PAM8610, have a direct DC connection from the amplifier IC to the speaker in a 'bridge' configuration where both speaker wires are active. If either side is grounded the amp will be shorted out. Amps with single-ended output sometimes 'ground' the speaker to the positive supply rail, which will short out the piano PSU when this external circuit is connected.

Comment: Hi user314164, Knowing the make / model of the digital piano and gaining access to its schematic would help in solving the problem.

Comment: Hi Bruce, I agree with you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found information on the PAM8610:

https://components101.com/modules/pam8610-audio-stereo-amplifier-module

It could be that you have the ground input connection of the amplifier tied to the high side of the speaker output of the digital piano. If one side of the speaker is grounded, this would short out the output and you would not get any sound. Try reversing connections to the speaker. But first, maybe use a multimeter to see what terminals connect to ground.

Comment: I double checked with a multimeter and when I measure the resistance between the GND of the power supply and any of the built-in speaker wires, it's 4k ohms. Also, this problem happens if there is no external speaker connected to the mini amplifier (I did the test today). I made a video showing exactly my wires, could you please take a look? I edited my question to put the video! Could you kindly take a look at it?